# Loading properties from config map in spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I have property:

```
@Value("${kafka.bootstrapServers}")
public String kafkaBootstrapServer;
```

then I have this properties in `default-kafka.properties` and in config map in kube

in spring boot 2 I have bootstrap yamp:

```
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      config:
        sources:
          - name: "my-app"
          - name: "my-app-kafka"
```

and this property is correctly loaded from config map:

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-19T09:32:13.804+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Searching for key 'kafka.bootstrapServers' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties'","logger_name":"org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"SERVERNAME":"my-app-588c8889c-8vs4m"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-19T09:32:13.804+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Searching for key 'kafka.bootstrapServers' in PropertySource 'bootstrapProperties-configmap.my-app-kafka'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"SERVERNAME":"my-app-588c8889c-8vs4m"}
```

now I try to port this app to spring boot 3. So there is no more bootstrap and I add this to kubernetes.yaml

```
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: kubernetes
    import: 'kubernetes:'
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      config:
        sources:
          - name: "my-app"
          - name: "my-app-kafka"
      reload:
        enabled: true
```

but there is different order and this property is loaded from default properties and not configmap:

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-19T08:57:30.818239134+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Searching for key 'kafka.bootstrapServers' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties'","logger_name":"org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"SERVERNAME":"my-app-7577888684-6fpdz"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-19T08:57:30.818258156+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Searching for key 'kafka.bootstrapServers' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"SERVERNAME":"my-app-7577888684-6fpdz"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-19T08:57:30.818269302+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Searching for key 'kafka.bootstrapServers' in PropertySource 'servletConfigInitParams'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"SERVERNAME":"my-app-7577888684-6fpdz"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-19T08:57:30.81827849+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Searching for key 'kafka.bootstrapServers' in PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"SERVERNAME":"my-app-7577888684-6fpdz"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-19T08:57:30.818289512+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Searching for key 'kafka.bootstrapServers' in PropertySource 'systemProperties'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"SERVERNAME":"my-app-7577888684-6fpdz"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-19T08:57:30.818299641+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Searching for key 'kafka.bootstrapServers' in PropertySource 'systemEnvironment'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"SERVERNAME":"my-app-7577888684-6fpdz"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-19T08:57:30.818311789+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Searching for key 'kafka.bootstrapServers' in PropertySource 'random'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"SERVERNAME":"my-app-7577888684-6fpdz"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-19T08:57:30.818322033+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Searching for key 'kafka.bootstrapServers' in PropertySource 'cachedrandom'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"SERVERNAME":"my-app-7577888684-6fpdz"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-19T08:57:30.818331324+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Searching for key 'kafka.bootstrapServers' in PropertySource 'KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE_PROPERTY_SOURCE'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"SERVERNAME":"my-app-7577888684-6fpdz"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-19T08:57:30.818340997+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Searching for key 'kafka.bootstrapServers' in PropertySource 'springCloudClientHostInfo'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"SERVERNAME":"my-app-7577888684-6fpdz"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-19T08:57:30.818350349+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Searching for key 'kafka.bootstrapServers' in PropertySource 'Config resource 'class path resource [application-default-kafka.properties]' via location 'optional:classpath:/''","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"SERVERNAME":"my-app-7577888684-6fpdz"}
```

any advice how to keep same order of loading properties in spring boot 3 ?

**UPDATE**

searching in configmap is after classpath properties

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-19T10:02:46.709702689+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Searching for key 'kafka.bootstrap' in PropertySource 'composite-configmap'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver","thread_name":"main","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000,"SERVERNAME":"my-app-74f89d456b-jtksn"}
```